# NSDateFormatter adds 10hours?

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I'm trying to get two dates from strings, so code below:

```
         NSString *serverDateString     = array[0];
         NSString *nextEventDateString  = array[1];
         NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
         [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm dd.MM.yyyy"];

         timer.serverTime           = [dateFormatter dateFromString:serverDateString];
         timer.nextEventTime        = [dateFormatter dateFromString:nextEventDateString];
```

But what i get :

```
(lldb) po serverDateString
12:15 16.03.2015

(lldb) po nextEventDateString
00:00 17.03.2015

(lldb) po timer.serverTime
2015-03-15 22:15:00 +0000

(lldb) po timer.nextEventTime
2015-03-16 22:00:00 +0000
```

Is there some my mistakes?

Comment: Unrelated, but do I correctly infer from the lack of AM/PM designation that the hour in those date strings is 24-hour clock? If so, use `HH` rather than `hh`.

Comment: The `serverTime` and `nextEventTime` are being displayed in GMT/UTC, but you instructed the `NSDateFormatter` to parse those two strings as if those were local timezone representations. Are those two strings local timezone values or Zulu/GMT/UTC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `dateFromString:` depends on the timezone of your `NSDateFormatter`. So you need to tell your formatter, which timezone to use:

```
NSString *serverDateString     = array[0];
NSString *nextEventDateString  = array[1];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm dd.MM.yyyy"];

// Set the time zone here
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"CET"]];

// If not sure, this will give you a list of abbreviations
// NSLog(@"%@", [NSTimeZone abbreviationDictionary]);

timer.serverTime           = [dateFormatter dateFromString:serverDateString];
timer.nextEventTime        = [dateFormatter dateFromString:nextEventDateString];
```

If you are unsure about the timezone abbreviations you can use, you can use `NSTimeZone abbreviationDictionary` as shown above.

Comment: Thanks, it worked + i may add this : i used GMT, but timer.serverTime was returning nil. My mistake was is 'h' is about hours 1-12 and i need 'H' that is 0-23.